# KSQLDB: Group By Concate Equivalent

Tags: ksqldb

I have a stream such as the following:

```
ksql> select * from customerstream;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|EVENT                                                                                                                                |CONTENT                                                                                                                              |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|create                                                                                                                               |{name=bob, location=NY, id=1}                                                                                                        |
|update                                                                                                                               |{location=AM}                                                                                                                        |
|update                                                                                                                               |{location=BER}                                                                                                                       |
|update                                                                                                                               |{name=bob_new}                                                                                                                       |
|delete                                                                                                                               |{id=1}                                                                                                                               |
```

Now I would like to group the events by the id and ignore customers, that have already been deleted.

I look for something like this:

```
select content['id'] from customer group by content['id'] HAVING 'delete' not in collect_set(event);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!

```
select 
content['id'],latest_by_offset(content['location']),collect_set(event) 
from customerstream group by content['id'] HAVING NOT 
ARRAY_CONTAINS(collect_set(event),'delete')  emit changes;
```